# giving write permission to nginx public folder on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, html, nginx

Just did a fresh installation of nginx on my local machine.

I am trying to give write permission to nginx public folder but I get this error mod: ***cannot access '/usr/share/nginx/html': No such file or directory***

the public file path for the nginx server is ***file:///usr/share/nginx/html***

Please assist

Comment: **1.** Where/when/how do you get the error? **2.** The path you're getting the error on is not the same as the path you say is the public path? If the path that's ending with `public_html` doesn't exist, it doesn't exist.

Comment: /usr/share/nginx/public_html' exist. I copied and pasted the folder in the terminal, it does exist

Comment: You really need to update your question with more info. What are you trying to do and how? How and when are you getting that error? We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should make sure is, your path is correct. Confirm if the folder name is "html" or "public_html".

Then you apply your permission using "sudo" prefix if you are not root user.

Comment: You can try:  sudo chmod -R 0777 /usr/share/nginx/public_html

Comment: the folder name was html, but when i paste the folder to confirm the file path it was showing public_html, I just removed the public_ and it worked. Does it also give permission to sub folder also?

Comment: When we use "-R", it is applicable to all sub folders of that folder.